# Code to download file from FTP with WinSCP .NET assembly does not connect, but I can connect in WinSCP GUI

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

I need to download a file from FTP thru WinSCP .NET assembly. I have this code currently but the error says Authentication failed.

```
try
{
    SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
    {
        Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
        HostName = "172.xx.xxx.xx",
        UserName = "usersample",
        Password = "P@ssw0rd",
        PortNumber = 21
    };

    using (Session session = new Session())
    {
        // Connect
        session.Open(sessionOptions);

        // Download files
        TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
        transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

        TransferOperationResult transferResult;
        transferResult =
            session.GetFiles(
                "/HST/sample.txt", "C:\\Users\\john\\Documents\\SampleFolder\\",
                false, transferOptions);

        // Throw on any error
        transferResult.Check();

        // Print results
        foreach (TransferEventArgs transfer in transferResult.Transfers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Download of {0} succeeded", transfer.FileName);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I got the code from this reference: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles

Originally, it has the following:

```
SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
```

But I removed it since I don't have it and I think it's for SFTP (not sure)
I've tried the credentials manually and they work. I am able to login.
Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's WinSCP FAQ for your kind of situation:
[Why I cannot connect/transfer using script, when I can using GUI (or vice versa)?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_script_vs_gui)

---

The easiest solution, to start with, is to use [Generate transfer code](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#code) function from your GUI session, to get a working code template.

- Login in GUI;
- Select the file to download in remote panel and the target local directory in local panel;
- Use *Download* command;
- On the [Download transfer options dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_copy), use *Transfer settings > Generate Code*;
- [Generate transfer code dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#code) opens. Select the *.NET assembly tab* and make sure *C#* language is selected.

  [image]

Comment: OMG. You just saved my life. Thank you very much. I followed your precised instructions and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

You need SSH host key fingerprint in addition to your credentials for SSH connection.

> You should get an SSH host key fingerprint along with your credentials
>   from a server administrator. Knowing the host key fingerprint and thus
>   being able to verify it is an integral part of securing an SSH
>   connection. It prevents man-in-the-middle attacks.

This may help you to get your Host-Key:

https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_hostkey

https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_fsinfo

Comment: The OP is using FTP, not SSH (SFTP).